# Implementing JS code to change CSS elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables, tags

This is a code excerpt from my program, and I would like to know how o change this in order to adjust the top and left values by using JS variables in the  tag which is above it in order to randomize its position in a 9x9 grid. I have already tried using code such as h1.style.left = `${left}%`;
but it's simply not working for me.

```
<style>
            #backgroundColor {
                background-color: rgba(211, 233, 254, 0.779);
                margin-top: 5%;
            }

            #content {
                text-align: center;
                width: 100%;
            }
/* I want to change the top and left values to correspond with JS variables. */
            h1 {
                position: absolute;
                top: 1.75%;
                /* Alter values in a grid by 10.75. Make a varible in <script>, go from 1.75-87.75 */
                left: 27.25%;
                /* Alter values in a grid by 5.5. Make a variable in <script>, go from 27.25-71.25 */
                color: rgb(47, 0, 0)
            }

            div {
                position: relative;
                text-align: center;
            }

            image {
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }
            
            .center {
                display: block;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                width: 50%;
            }

            .numbers {
                font-family: monospace;
                font-size: xx-large;
                font-weight: normal;
                font: Menlo;
            }

            .title {
                font-family: monospace;
                font-style: italic;
                font-weight: lighter;
                font-size: xx-large;
            }

            .subtitle {
                font-family: monospace;
                font: Courier;
                font-size: large;
                font-weight: lighter;
            }
        </style>
```

I tried using the following JS Code, but it did not work. Any solutions?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    "use strict";
            function getNumCoords(ifX, ifY) {
                const numGridMax = 8;
                var yPos = Math.floor(Math.random()*numGridMax);
                var xPos = Math.floor(Math.random()*numGridMax);
                if (ifX === 1) {
                    return (xPos*5.5)+27.25;
                }
                if (ifX === 1) {
                    return (yPos*10.75)+1.75;
                }
            }
            var outputX = getNumCoords(1, 0) + "%";
            var outputY = getNumCoords(0, 1) + "%";
            var number = document.getElementById("random");

    </script>
```

Comment: *I tried using the following JS Code: ... In order to change the CSS Elements* - I think you posted the wrong code. None of that does anything with style at all

Comment: How would I do something like that then?

Comment: Oh, so that's the right code. DOM elements have a [style property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) - you can change the `.style.top` and `.style.left`  for example

Comment: Can you create a minimal example, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example At the moment I cannot understand what you are trying to do as the function only returns a single value and only then under rather resticted circumstances. Should the second 'if' be testing y not x?

Comment: @Deathstalker, You're checking **ifX** again instead of **ifY**.

Comment: Yes it should, thanks!

Comment: @Deathstalker Down votes are not meant to be toxic; they're meant to signal a post should be improved.  That said, I did flag that comment on your other question, but you deleted it before I could say that.

Comment: How do you create a good MRE?

Comment: @Deathstalker There is no better guide I can provide than the one on [mre].  Just try to reduce the problem to only the necessary parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example. Note that the `left` value must be a string, using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) works nicely.

```js
const h1 = document.getElementById("h1");
let left = 0;

function mover() {
  if (left < 100) {
    left += 10;
    h1.style.left = `${left}px`;
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval);
    h1.textContent = "Done";
  }
}
const interval = setInterval(mover, 1000);
```

```css
h1 {
  color: #008;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="h1">Header</h1>
```